# Having template function defination in cpp file - Not work for VC6

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have the following source code :

```
// main.cpp
#include "a.h"

int main() {
    A::push(100);
}
```

---

```
// a.cpp
#include "a.h"

template <class T>
void A::push(T t) {
}

template void A::push(int t);
```

---

```
// a.h
#ifndef A_H
class A {
public:
    template <class T>
    static void push(T t);
};
#endif
```

---

The code compiled charming and no problem under VC2008.

But when come to my beloved VC6, it give me error :

> main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved
>   external symbol "public: static void
>   __cdecl A::push(int)" (?push@A@@SAXH@Z)

Any workaround? I just want to ensure my function definition is re-inside cpp file.

Comment: Um. Why would you be using VC6 when you have VC2008? That's a huge step backwards. There's a good chance that VC6 is failing on you because it's not as standards compliant as VC2008 is. VC6 is pretty ancient at this point. Do you have to use it for an old computer or something?

Comment: Migration from VC6 is not an options, as the legacy code based rely heavily on 3rd parties VC6 only libraries.

Comment: I agree with Jonathan.  If you want modern support with the same old functionality, make sure your program is compiled without managed code (turn off the Common Language Runtime (CLR) support).  Of course, that means no garbage collection, .NET, etc., just like in VC6, which didn't have those things inbuilt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem solved by using

```
// main.cpp
#include "a.h"

int main() {
    A::push<int>(100);
}
```

It seems that you need to provide more hint to VC6, compared with VC2008.